# Driver Scanner detect driver needed

Tags: drivers

I'm currently fixing the laptop of my friend. Her laptop is kinda old and it's not a well know brand (Redfox Navigator), so that means there is no online support.

Is there any software that will scan the system and look for the driver that it needs?

Note: The laptop can't connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of websites that will do online scans.  I've only found one that I know of that will allow you to do an offline scan.  http://driverrobot.com/  It's subscription based and I've never used it, but they claim to be able to do offline scans.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ma-config.com/en

It is a free web site that install a certified plugin on your browser and list missing and outdated drivers and point links to download then.

- Works on Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera
- Require Flash Player installed
- Detection for 32-bit and 64-bit system
- Windows 2000 and XP SP1 or above

There is also a [offline detection tool](http://www.ma-config.com/en/detectoffline) witch you run offline it generates a result file, and you have to use another computer with internet to upload it to get the drivers.

---

There are tons of sites that claim to do the same, but most of then are paid services, and just give you a demo, and most don't let you actually download the drives unless you pay.

P.S. I do not work for then or anything like that, I use it for my personal use.